# How to bind div using Jquery web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Jquery web service I need to bind json value to div

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Newdashboard.aspx/finalvalue",              
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(),
                datatype: 'json',
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d == '[]') {
                        alert('No Matches found');
                    }
                    else {
                        // here bind div
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert("check once...");
                }
            });
```

`finalvalue` method gives a table consist only on value (like 50/90/33)

I need to bind to a div with that result, how can I do this.

Comment: What do you mean by bind?

Comment: $("#div").html(data.d);

Comment: Post example of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d == '[]') {
                    alert('No Matches found');
                }
                else {
                    //  here you amend the data from service.
                    $("div#divId").html(data.d);
                }
            }
```

[jQuery HTML](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is used for the solution, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery function .append(). This will add the result to the end of the div.

http://api.jquery.com/append/